# How to use Nested IIF statement in ms access sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

i'm using MS Access (2010) DataBase for my project and i want to use nested IIF Statement in ms access SQL query. but i got the error like "Syntax Error in query Expression" in the sqb-query statement.
below i mentioned the sample code -

```
IIF(SimpleLoan=0,0,transDemand.SimpleInstallment,IIF(transDemand.SimpleInstallment=0,select Installment from LoanMaster where FYear=(select max(FYear) from LoanMaster),0)) AS SimpleInstallment
```

So please suggest me how can i solve it ?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.  Your query does not make sense.

Comment: Sir this is the whole query which i'm trying to execute. but still it show's the error towards the sub query. This is the sample Query - "SELECT Customer.AccNumber2, Customer.Name,IIF(transDemand.SimpleLoan>=0,IIF(transDemand.SimpleInstallment=0,select Installment from LoanMaster where FYear=(select max(FYear) from LoanMaster),0)) AS SimpleInstallment, 
FROM Customer INNER JOIN transDemand ON Customer.AccNumber = transDemand.AccNumber
WHERE DemandDate=(select max(DemandDate) from transDemand);"

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is that the outer `IIF` has 4 arguments instead of 3, check them here:

```
IIF(
  SimpleLoan=0,
  0,
  transDemand.SimpleInstallment,
  IIF(
    transDemand.SimpleInstallment=0,
    select Installment from LoanMaster where FYear=(select max(FYear) from LoanMaster),
    0
  )
) AS SimpleInstallment
```

See this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)
For `IIF` the syntax is:

```
IIf(expr , truepart , falsepart)
```

Comment: I modified the query but still i got the error with sub query.

Comment: the modified query- IIF(SimpleLoan>=0,IIF(transDemand.SimpleInstallment=0,select Installment from LoanMaster where FYear=(select max(FYear) from LoanMaster),0)) AS SimpleInstallment

Comment: Now you have 2 arguments instead of 3 inside the outer IIF.